# Проблема с XDebug и VirtualBox: Failed to execute validation script: 'unknown reason'

Tags: xdebug, php, phpstorm

Никак не удается настроить удаленный XDEBUG из PHP Storm в VirtualBox

Исходные данные:
Мой компьютер имеет IP - 10.10.0.103
Виртуальная машина - 10.10.0.104

XDEBUG конфигурация

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 10.10.0.103
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

Собственно настраиваю в PHP Storm удаленную отладку.

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Сеть настроена так

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 1):

Предположу - локальный путь не подмонтирован на виртуалке, т.е. Директория /webserver  не привязана через "Общие папки" virtualbox.